# Office 365 Impersonation

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to send an email from my Office 365 account while impersonating User2.

```
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

            string fromUserEmail = new string("User2@domain");
                       
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("User1@domain", "password");
            service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, fromUserEmail);
            service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);

            email.ToRecipients.Add("someone@somewhere");
            email.ReplyTo.Add(replyToEmail);
            email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
            email.Body = new MessageBody("Test message");

            email.Send();
        }
```

I get a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' on email.Send().  When I comment out the service.Impersonation it works.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  I needed permission via

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Name:User1_impersonation -Role:ApplicationImpersonation -User: "User1@domain"
```

I don't know why Visual Studio didn't provide a more useful error message.